# How large should the call of the remote station be on the QSL card?

Tags: qsl-card

I have designed my first QSL card but I'm worried that I may have reserved too little space for the call of the remote station. I'm worried that the buro might have trouble with it. However, I see many QSL cards on [this examples page](http://kb3ifh.homestead.com/More-QSL-Examples.html) with a fairly small field as well. My card currently looks like this:

[image]

(I prefer to not put the picture online so that it's a surprise when you get it).

I would write the remote call under 'CALL' in letters of about 3.5mm high.

Would the buro be happy with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days a majority of DXpeditions and large contest stations print the QSL data on address labels to be stuck on the QSL cards.  10-point type is common, which is about 3.5 mm high, so your plan should be fine.  You might want to leave yourself more height in case you write cards by hand, unless you are accustomed to writing neat small letters.

The bureau should be satisfied with anything that doesn't make the sorter hunt for the call sign, and is easily legible.  It is important to make sure that your cards are exactly 3.5 in x 5.5 in (88.9 mm x 139.7 mm), the standard size for non-Japanese QSL cards.